# Show this is an Open Cover of (0,1)

Tags: real-analysis

I'm going through some material for this real analysis course (again) and stumbled upon this open covering of (0,1): $\kappa_n = (\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n})$.
Since, for $n \to \infty$, $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ and $1-\frac{1}{n} \to 1$ it's obvious, that $\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} \kappa_n = (0,1)$. However, I have some difficulties actually proving this. For the $\kappa_n$'s to be an open cover of (0,1) there must $\forall x \in (0,1) \exists n \in \mathbb{N}, s.t. x \in \kappa_n$. Let $x \in (0,1)$, then, by the archimedian axiom, there exists $n > \frac{1}{x}$ and therefore $\frac{1}{n} < x$ and that's it for the lower bound, but I'm stuck for the upper bound -- how to prove that also $x < 1 - \frac{1}{n}$ (for the same n, obviously). Maybe, if we take $n$ to be the smallest $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < x$, then $x \leq \frac{1}{n-1}$; but I don't know where to go from there (and whether it's a good idea at all). I'm sure this is really easy stuff, but I just can't get my head around it. Help appreciated!

Comment: $$x < 1 - \tfrac{1}{n} \iff \tfrac{1}{n} < 1-x$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider three cases at first: $x=1/2$, $0<x<1/2$, and $1/2<x<1$. Then, see if you see a pattern and can simplify.

See below for solution:

> By looking at these cases, we notice that if $0<x<1/2$, we are closer to the left endpoint, so we select $n$ such that $1/n<x$ and we get $x<1-1/n$ for free.  If $1/2<x<1$, we are closer to the *right* endpoint so we must select $n$ such that $1/n<1-x$ (see Daniel Fischer's comment), and then we get $1/n<x$ for free.  Thus given any $x\in (0,1)$, we let $N=\max\{n_1,n_2\}$ where $1/n_1<x$ and $1/n_2<1-x$; the number $x$ will then be in $\kappa_N$.

Also, a trivial note: your $\kappa_1$ and $\kappa_2$ are actually empty, so you don't really need to include them in your union.

Comment: In each case it follows that 1-x < 1-1/n; when x=1/2 then x=1-x < 1-1/n. In the 2nd case x < 1-x. In the 3rd: 1-x < x < 1-1/n. This is intuitive, because here 1-x represents the reflection of x across a vertical line going through 1/2. However, I don't see how to prove the result without making this case analysis.